# How to truncate text elements conditionally in Angular?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, resize, truncate

In my Angular component I have a text consisting of two values. In my template:

```
 <svg-icon [name]="someName" class="d-inline-block"></svg-icon>

 <strong class="any">
    {{ program.name }}
    <span class="pcr">{{ program.pcr }}</span>
 </strong>
```

What I want to do is to truncate the text with the elipsis (...) but in a special way.

When there's lack of space for the whole text to display, I want to initially truncate the `program.name`. Resizing the screen to smaller, the text can be shortened until it has no less than 5 characters (excluding ellipsis). If there is still not enough space I want to truncate the `program.prc`.

I tried to make a directive using `Hostbinding` but I have no idea how to approach the logic. Maybe there's kind of ready solution for similar problems? Anybody could help?

Comment: You can try something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ydvg9enb/) using css. Try to resize the window to see the effect.

Comment: I know this css property but my problem with the case I described is how to implement the logic. I have two elements in the span. And I want one of them to react first and the second one to react just when the first eement has 5 characters left.

Comment: This is going to be quite complicated to do in Angular, I would write you out a solution but I don't really have the time at the moment. You could use the solution @palaѕн mentions, but add an extra span with a `min-width` around `{{program.name}}`?

Comment: The best solution for the problem I described can be found here: [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ttygrx?file=app%2Fitem.component.ts](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ttygrx?file=app%2Fitem.component.ts)